# Pulling a field from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my full page code:

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "null";
$dbname = "logs";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'd82Kap3'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['ip'];

?>
```

This is my table structure: http://prntscr.com/7we7ck

I am trying to make it echo all the records in the field "ip".

Comment: And the the problem is ? What is your actual output ?

Comment: I highly advice you read up on [Why you **really** shouldn't use `mysql_` and `mysqli_` extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

*Please* refer to the [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: the sql looks wrong - use backticks around the table name rather than single quotes

Comment: `SELECT ip FROM d82Kap3`. Yw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while` loop for it.

**Example**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'd82Kap3'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo $row['ip']."<br />";
}
```

**Note**

`mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

**Update**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "null";
$dbname = "logs";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `d82Kap3`");

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
     echo $row['ip']."<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Does not work. I will update my post with the full page code.

Comment: @user3724476 I have update my answer again. There was little issue in code. Never use single `'` quote with table name in query.

Answer (score 0):

Dont mix `mysql` and `mysqli`

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "null";
$dbname = "logs";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM d82Kap3");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
echo $row['ip'];

?>
```

Comment: Does not work. I will update my post with the full page code.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'd82Kap3'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{
 echo $row['ip'];
}
```

Comment: Does not work. I will update my post with the full page code.

Comment: remove single quotes from table name.
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d82Kap3");
And use function mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array.